# LATEX : How keep multiline text together after vertical line?

Tags: alignment, text, vspace

I am creating a list of variables with their descriptions. On the left side, is the variable name and on the right side is the variable description. When the text description is one line, the text is fine as in ***uvax_d*** and ***uvax2_d*** .However, when the description is longer as in ***sdex*** the second line spills below the vertical line.

I want the vertical line to always be longer than the text description:

```
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,leftmargin=10em,style=nextline, font=\bfseries\itshape]
\item [uvax\_d] $\bigg \vert$ Date when vaccines became universally available.
\item [uvax2\_d] $\bigg \vert$ Two month mark after vaccines became universally available.
\item [sdex] $\bigg \vert$ Government Response Stringency Index: composite measure based on 9 response indicators including school closures, workplace closures, and travel bans, rescaled to a value from 0 to 100 (100 = strictest response).
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

[sidenote: This is my first ever post, so I am still figuring out how this actually works.]

Comment: the output you show is what I would expect from the input you show except you have some unshown code making the label italic. What output do you want? Also please  always post  a complete small example that shows the problem

Comment: This is my first ever post, so I am still figuring out how this actually works. 

But the I want the output to be as "uvax2\_d" where the vertical line encompasses the whole text next to it. So my problem is actually with  "sdex" because the second line goes below the vertical space.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `\vrule` followed by a `\parbox` for the item text:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=3em,style=nextline, font=\bfseries\itshape]
\item[foo]\vrule\quad\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{\lipsum[2][1]}
\item[bar]\vrule\quad\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{\lipsum[2][2-5]}
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2][2-9]
\end{document}
```

Type this is a bit tedious,  but you can  simplify the code with a macro,  and even make your own environment without using the `enumitem` package nor latex lists. A start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\newcommand\ditem[3][3em]{%
\par\makebox[#1][l]{\em\bfseries #2}\vrule\hfill
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1-\parindent-1em}{#3}\par}
\newenvironment{ditems}{\medskip\parindent\leftmargin\parskip1em}{\bigskip\par} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{ditems}
\ditem{foo}{\lipsum[3][1-3]}
\ditem{bah}{\lipsum[3][5-9]}
\ditem{baz}{\lipsum[3][10-18]}
\ditem[10em]{whatever too long}{\lipsum[2][1-3]}
\ditem[10em]{whatever too short}{\lipsum[3][1]}
\end{ditems}
\lipsum[2][2-9]
end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome!  This is exactly what I was looking for.